# Are questions about the future and trends in freelancing industry on topic

Tags: discussion

I am trying to see if we can be trend analysers and provide value that way to anyone wanting to influence the industry in future if not trend setters ourself.

Would this however be very far off from the original scope of this website?

Comment: It probably depends on the types of questions. Maybe you could give some examples?

Comment: I am considering things like, Can stackoverflow become a good freelancing platform in the near or distant future because it has the social proof of value and jobs are already here, and in effect freelancing would be the job of the future

Comment: Another question is what are the hindrances in creating a open source commissionless frelancing platform

Answer (score 1):

This would be off-topic, mostly because it's a theoretical "what if?" question; none of the answers can realistically be backed up, and it would possibly be misleading to future readers.

Trends in general don't really work with the Q&A model, as content here tends to stick around for a long time. We tend to focus on a specific problem that someone has at a specific point in time.

In addition, the "freelancing industry" is wildly variable depending on *where* in the world you are, not just *when*, so broader, this-is-what-the-future-holds answers don't seem like a particularly valuable way to contribute.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I agree with that line of thought, but would something like my question in comments above be on topic?

Answer (score 0):

The only question I could see as on-topic would be something like "how does a freelancer keep up with the industry?"

So it wouldn't be asking for advice on specific trends right now, but rather asking about how one keeps up in general. The answer to that question would be applicable into the future too.

As for "what are the hindrances in creating a open source commissionless frelancing platform?"

That seems to me to be a business-type question. Why does *any* website/business work/fail? It's not really freelance related, but rather just comes down to the usual business stuff. Market saturation, is there a demand, need for a huge user base, pure luck, etc. I suspect that'd be closed because it's not really freelancing related.